# Проблема при подключении к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть три php файла. `index.php` (страница с формой), `verification.php` (обработчик), `bd.php` (подключение к БД).

Если все три файла закидываю прямо в корень сайта - все работает отлично. Если в корне оставляю только index.php, а остальные два помещаю, на пример:   корень>>>php>>>registration>>>а тут два файла - Уже ни чего не работает.

---

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once ("bd.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>БЛОГ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <form method="post">
        <p><input class="input" name="email" type="text" value="Почтовый ящик" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /></p> 
        <p><input class="input" name="login" type="text" value="Псевдоним" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /></p>
        <p><input class="input" name="password" type="Password" value="**********" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /></p>
        <p><button  name="submit" type="submit" formaction="verification.php" class="button_1">Регистрация</button></p>
        <p><button type="submit" formaction="Вход.php" class="button_2">Вход</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**verification.php**

```
<?php
    include_once ("bd.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['login']))  {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Введите логин! </font>';
        } 
        elseif (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $_POST['login'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">В поле "Логин" введены недопустимые символы! Только буквы, цифры и подчеркивание!</font>';
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Введите пароль!</font>';
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/\A(\w){6,20}\Z/", $_POST['password'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Пароль слишком короткий! Пароль должен быть не менее 6 символов!</font>';
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['email'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Введите E-mail!</font>';
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['email'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">E-mail имеет недопустимий формат! Например, name@gmail.com!</font>';
        }

        else{
            $login = $_POST['login'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $mdPassword = md5($password);
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $rdate = date("d-m-Y в H:i");
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

            $query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
            $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
                echo '<font color="red">Пользователь с таким логином зарегистрирован!</font>';
            }
            else {
                $query2 = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                $sql = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    echo '<font color="red">Пользователь с таким e-mail уже зарегистрирован!</font>';
                }
                else{
                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (login, password, email, reg_date, name_user, lastname )
                              VALUES ('$login', '$mdPassword', '$email', '$rdate', '$name', '$lastname')";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
                    echo '<font color="green">Вы успешно зарегистрировались!</font>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**bd.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","654321");
mysql_select_db ("radnk2xz_users");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$id_user = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

**так работает отлично**

---

**А если в корне только index.php, а остальные два файла в отдельной папке.**

**почему то уже работать не хочет.**

> Access denied for user 'radnk2xz'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once ("php/registration/bd.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>БЛОГ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <form method="post">
        <p><input class="input" name="email" type="text" value="Почтовый ящик" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /></p> 
        <p><input class="input" name="login" type="text" value="Псевдоним" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /></p>
        <p><input class="input" name="password" type="Password" value="**********" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" /></p>
        <p><button  name="submit" type="submit" formaction="php/registration/verification.php" class="button_1">Регистрация</button></p>
        <p><button type="submit" formaction="Вход.php" class="button_2">Вход</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**verification.php**

```
<?php
    include_once ("php/registration/bd.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['login']))  {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Введите логин! </font>';
        } 
        elseif (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $_POST['login'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">В поле "Логин" введены недопустимые символы! Только буквы, цифры и подчеркивание!</font>';
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Введите пароль!</font>';
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/\A(\w){6,20}\Z/", $_POST['password'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Пароль слишком короткий! Пароль должен быть не менее 6 символов!</font>';
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['email'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">Введите E-mail!</font>';
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['email'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red">E-mail имеет недопустимий формат! Например, name@gmail.com!</font>';
        }

        else{
            $login = $_POST['login'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $mdPassword = md5($password);
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $rdate = date("d-m-Y в H:i");
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

            $query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
            $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
                echo '<font color="red">Пользователь с таким логином зарегистрирован!</font>';
            }
            else {
                $query2 = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                $sql = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    echo '<font color="red">Пользователь с таким e-mail уже зарегистрирован!</font>';
                }
                else{
                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (login, password, email, reg_date, name_user, lastname )
                              VALUES ('$login', '$mdPassword', '$email', '$rdate', '$name', '$lastname')";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
                    echo '<font color="green">Вы успешно зарегистрировались!</font>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**bd.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","654321");
mysql_select_db ("radnk2xz_users");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$id_user = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Довольно забавно...
Заметьте, у Вас в ошибке написано 'radnk2xz'@'localhost'. То есть имя пользователя обрезается до нижнего подчеркивания. Я, честно сказать, не знаю почему так происходит. Попробуйте экранировать это самое нижнее подчеркивание.  Может поможет...

Comment: печально (

Comment: Так экранирование не помогло?

Comment: Я новичок (не умею пока что).

Comment: А с помощью mysql консольки получается войти? (`mysql -u radnk2xz_users -p radnk2xz_users`)

Answer (score 2):

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
include_once ($root . "/php/registration/bd.php");
```

странно что никто не помог. )))

Answer (score 1):

```
  <p><button  name="submit" type="submit" formaction="verification.php" class="button_1">Регистрация</button></p>
```

Ну так если перемещаешь файлы в другую папку, то и пути нужно изменять!

**formaction="php/verification.php"**

Comment: я так и делаю